# How to use a react native npm package with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

is it possible to use a react native npm package in react?

because when importing the package that uses react-native in the browser console, the error "main.js:3068 Uncaught ReferenceError: react is not defined" appears

I am generating a pdf (react-pdf) and that package uses react-native components, I need to give styles. the "StyleSheet" does not allow to use rem and that's why I want to use "EStyleSheet"

my webpack configuration

```html
const webpack = require('webpack');

const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {

    mode: 'development',
    entry: path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.js"),

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        publicPath: '/'

    },
    externals: {
        "react-native": true,

    },


    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        port: 81,

    },

    module: {
        rules: [


            {
                test: /\.?js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
                    }
                }
            },

            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['file-loader?name=[name].[ext]']
            }
        ]
    },

    resolve: {
        alias: {
            stream: "stream-browserify",
            zlib: "browserify-zlib"
        },


        fallback: {
            util: require.resolve('util/'),
            assert: require.resolve('assert/'),
            stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
            zlib: require.resolve('browserify-zlib'),
            buffer: require.resolve("buffer/"),
            events: require.resolve("events/"),
            string_decoder: require.resolve("string_decoder/"),

        },
    },


    plugins: [


        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.html"),
            Filename: './index.html',
            Favicon: './public/favicon.ico'
        }),

        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({

            Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
            process: 'process/browser',

        }),
    ],


}
```

my package.json =

```html
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack serve",
    "build": "webpack",
    "watch": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack --watch --config webpack.dev.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "browser-process": "^0.0.1",
    "browserify-zlib": "^0.2.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "filepond": "^4.30.4",
    "filepond-plugin-file-validate-size": "^2.2.7",
    "filepond-plugin-file-validate-type": "^1.2.8",
    "filepond-plugin-image-preview": "^4.6.11",
    "iconv-lite": "^0.6.3",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "npm": "^8.15.0",
    "posts": "^0.0.1",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-filepond": "^7.1.2",
    "react-native": "^0.69.2",
    "react-native-extended-stylesheet": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-html-to-pdf": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.16.0",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.13.0",
    "react-paginate": "^8.1.3",
    "react-pdf-html": "^1.1.8",
    "react-render-html": "^0.6.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-to-print": "^2.14.7",
    "somemodule": "^1.0.0",
    "stream": "^0.0.2",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "superagent": "^8.0.0",
    "util": "^0.12.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.9",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "interpolate-html-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.53.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.9.2"
  }
}
```

[Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYAZc.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that a React Native package will work. Especially if it's used to visualize a component, since React Native and React render items differently. The core is usually shareable, but when it specifically states that it's a React Native package, it's unlikely to work.